# Edit out a part of an audio file

Tags: applications, ringtone, mp3

How can I cut out a particular portion of the song and play the rest of the song?

for example my song is of 4 minutes and 11 seconds and I want to remove the section from `2:04` to `3:30` and play from `0:00` to`2:03` and then continue from `3:31` and end at `4:11`

I hope you got my problem can anyone help me with this?

Comment: How is this an Android-related question? Wouldn't you do that on a computer, using tools like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), for more comfortability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an app like **[WavePad Audio Editing App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nchsoftware.pocketwavepad)**. It is said to have the ability to work with multiple audio files. If you do not mind adverts, there is a [free version for this software](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nchsoftware.pocketwavepad_free) as well.

Comment: @John Yes, you *are* mistaken :) The app supports `.mp3` files

Comment: +1 seems like a better quality app then the MP3 Cutter.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an MP3 file, then you can use [MP3 Cutter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beka.tools.mp3cutter&hl=en).

It's free on the Play Store. If you need one for a different file format, let me know and I will find you a solution that supports that audio format.